# Oracle SQL Developer Missing Expression

Tags: oracle

Now I'm really new to MySQL and I'm trying to display information based on the date across the four tables below. But I keep receiving a 'missing expression' error, and there is a yellow line under MOVIE.

This is my code below:

```
SELECT SESSIONID,BRANCHID, MOVIENAME, SCREENCAPACITY
FROM SESSIONS, BRANCH, MOVIE, CAPACITY
WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID=BRANCH.BRANCHID
AND SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE='3-MAY-2016' OR SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE = '13-MAY=2016';
```

Comment: WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID=BRANCH.BRANCHID what is this trying to do?

Comment: convert your SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE first.

Comment: Im trying to display the relevant SESSIONS information based on the BRANCHID.

Comment: You've got four tables here, and yet you're only involving two of them in the query. What you need is a `LEFT JOIN`, perhaps.

Comment: First, you're joining 4 tables with only one join condition.  That means that you're generating multiple Cartesian products.  That is almost certainly a mistake.  You need at least 3 join conditions.  I'd strongly recommend using the SQL 99 syntax (`join`) rather than mixing join conditions and filter predicates in the `where` clause.  `13-May=2016` has an `=` character rather than a `-`.  Relying on implicit casting is a bad idea-- use explicit casts via `to_date` or specify date literals.  You would also need to provide aliases for the columns in the `select` that appear in multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

convert your date first

```
WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID=BRANCH.BRANCHID
AND TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE,'DD/MON/RR'), 'DD/MON/RR') = '06/JUN/16'
```

or in your case

```
WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID=BRANCH.BRANCHID
AND TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE,'D-MON-RRRR'), 'D-MON-RRRR') = '6-JUN-2016'
```

you can see date format in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm)

note: your condition wrong

```
AND SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE='3-MAY-2016' OR SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE = '13-MAY=2016';
```

should

```
AND SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE='3-MAY-2016' OR SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE = '13-MAY-2016';
```

Comment: Sorry I am actually using Oracle SQL Developer, not mySql.

Comment: i dont know is oracle SQL accept d-M-Y. can u post some data from your sessiondate ?

Comment: Sessiondate is in the form of: 06/JUN/16 For the 6th of June for example.

Comment: see my answer now

Comment: Im now getting a "column ambiguously defined" error. I feel like the error is occurring from the way im selecting data from 4 tables

Comment: SELECT SESSIONID,SESSIONS.BRANCHID, MOVIENAME, SCREENCAPACITY

Comment: ambiguously appear because branchID are in two table, sessions and branch, which one did u want to show? you have to chose

Comment: I need to display suburb of the branch (BRANCHSUBURB) the session is scheduled for, name of the movie (MOVIENAME) and screen capacity (SCREENCAPACITY) For the select dates

Answer (score 0):

I realised where my mistakes were, this is now the code that works:

```
SELECT SESSIONS.SESSIONID,BRANCH.BRANCHSUBURB,MOVIE.MOVIENAME,
SCREEN.SCREENCAPACITY, SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE
FROM SESSIONS,BRANCH,MOVIE,SCREEN
WHERE SESSIONS.BRANCHID = BRANCH.BRANCHID AND
SCREEN.BRANCHID = BRANCH.BRANCHID AND
SESSIONS.SCREENID = SCREEN.SCREENID AND
SESSIONS.MOVIEID = MOVIE.MOVIEID AND
(SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE = '3-MAY-2016'OR SESSIONS.SESSIONDATE = '13-MAY-2016');
```